# Why is my PSET1 Credit working in sandbox but not Check50?

Tags: c, cs50, luhn

I am having and issue where my PSET1 credit program works in the CS50 Sandbox and is able to determine whether a card is MasterCard, AMEX, or VISA based on its length and Luhn's algorithm. However, when I submit the code to Check50 it determines that all input is invalid.

Update: Instead of printing "INVALID" if the number does not adhere to Luhn's algorithm I changed it to print "nope" and found that all of the numbers checked by check50 result in an output of "nope," so I know the bug is somewhere in that part of the program. Like before, it still works in the sandbox.

I have looked for similar problems and solutions here and elsewhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Ask user to input number.
    long card_num;
    do
    {
        card_num = get_long("Number: ");   
    }
    //Check if card number is greater than zero.
    while (card_num < 0);

    //Starting with the second to last digit, multiply each digit by 2.
    //Add the products' digits together.
    int digit, prod, sum1, dig1, dig2;
    long holder = card_num;
    while (holder > 0)
    {
        digit = (holder / 10) % 10;
        prod = digit * 2;
        if (prod >= 10)
        {
            dig1 = (prod % 100 - (prod % 10)) / 10;
            dig2 = prod % 10;
            prod = dig1 + dig2;
        }
        sum1 = sum1 + prod;
        holder = holder / 100;
    }

    //Add sum1 to product of the other digits in the card number
    long holder1 = card_num;
    int dig3, sum2;
    while (holder1 > 0)
    {
        dig3 = holder1 % 10;
        sum2 = sum2 + dig3;
        holder1 = holder1 / 100;
    }

    //Check if the sum of the first and second sums has a final digit of 0.
    int last_sum = sum1 + sum2;
    if (last_sum % 10 != 0)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
    else
    {
        //Calculate number of digits
    int num_digits = 0;
    long holder3 = card_num;
    while (holder3 != 0)
    {
        holder3 = holder3 / 10;
        num_digits++;
    }

    //Find first two digits of card number
    long holder2 = card_num;
    while (holder2 > 100)
    {
         holder2 = holder2 / 10;
    }
    int firstdig, secdig;
    secdig = holder2 % 10;
    firstdig = holder2 / 10;

    //Check if VISA, Mastercard, or AMEX
    if (firstdig == 4)
    {
        if (num_digits == 13 || num_digits == 16)
        {
            printf ("VISA\n");
        }
    }
    else if (firstdig == 5 && secdig >= 1 && secdig <= 5)
    {
        if (num_digits == 16)
        {
            printf ("MASTERCARD\n");
        }
    }
    else if (firstdig == 3 && (secdig == 4 || secdig == 7))
    {
        if (num_digits == 15)
        {
            printf ("AMEX\n");
        }
    }
    else (printf("INVALID\n"));
    }
}
```

The expected results are MASTERCARD, VISA, AMEX, or INVALID. In the Sandbox it works, but Check50 gets INVALID for all numbers.

Comment: using: `else if (firstdig == 3 && (secdig == 4 || secdig == 7))
        {
            if (num_digits == 15)
            {
                printf ("AMEX\n");
            }
        }` as an example:  if the first 'if()' is entered and the second 'if()' fails, then nothing is output.  However, some error indication should be output

Comment: OT:  strongly suggest replacing the call to `get_long()` with something like: `scanf( "%lu", &card_num );`  because the header file: `cs50.h` is not portable and/or not available everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was that I had declared variables sum1 and sum2, but had not initialised them to any values, so they were assigned whatever value was in memory. When I initialised these too 0 the program functioned without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Different systems can have a different implementation of the size of a 'long'.

Suggest using `uint64_t`  from `stdint.h`  because

1. will always be the same size across different systems/implementations
2. the value needs to be unsigned as shifting signed values is problematic.

when calling `scanf()`, suggest using the format specifier: `SCNu64`

The `SCNu64` is from `inttypes.h`

an example for `scanf()`

```
uint64_t card_num;
scanf( "%" SCNu64, &card_num );
```

---

[how to validate a credit card number](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/validate-credit-card-information-43910.html)

Write down the last digit of the credit card number. This is the check sum digit you will use to verify the remainder of the credit card number.

List each digit of the credit card number, starting with the digit to the left of the check sum and moving to the left. If the credit card number has 16 digits, double the amount of every digit in the odd-positioned spots, working right to left, before adding it to your list. For credit cards with 15 digits, you would double the digits in the even-positioned spots. If doubling a digit results in a number higher than 10, add the two digits of the new number together and write that result on your list. For example, if the digit on the card is seven, doubling it would result in 14. The total of the two digits would then be five.

Total your list of numbers. Do not include the check sum digit in your total. If the total can be evenly divided by 10, the credit card has a valid number. If not, you should not process the credit card transaction.

---

[How to determine supplier of credit card](https://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/tell-card-number-credit-company-2321.html)

Identify a bank card's credit company by looking at the first number. Cards that start with a "3" are American Express. Those that start with "4" are Visa credit and debit cards, those that start with "5" are MasterCard credit and debit cards, and those that start with "6" are Discover credit cards. The service fee that is charged to merchants varies between card companies.

Count the digits in the credit card number. Most credit cards should contain either 15 or 16 digits. American Express credit cards contain 15. The other three major credit companies -- Visa, Mastercard and Discover -- have a 16-digit sequence on their cards.

Comment: I changed the type of variable from a long to a uint64_t, but this did not solve the problem and created another problem. The check50 grader still thinks all numbers are invalid and now does not reject non-numeric inputs, it simply outputs that they are invalid.

Comment: The OPs posted code does not implement the necessary algorithm to properly validate the card nor the necessary tests to determine which credit card company supplied the card